# Is there a way to make many requests to Facebook API without get blocked?

Tags: facebook, api, rate-limiting

I got a demand to make a webservice that centralizes informations of many facebook accounts (data, photos, friends). The problem is: it can receive lot of requests in short time. For that reason, i need an eficient way to get all information of facebook in few requests, or i will get blocked.

I have read about FQL, that i can suppose request info about many users in same query. If its true, will be perfect. But i didnt found detailed info about FQL limitations. So i have fear about confirm the viability of this demand, counting that FQL will solve all my problem.

Is it a good way to solve the problem? If not, what can be done?

Comment: Are you accessing the Facebook API anonymously? Typically you will be throttled immensely if you don't create a user-agent somewhere within the API for them to tie to your session. Also, if you're going to consume enormous amounts of Facebook data, you'll probably have to pay for some kind of privileged access. This is more general API usage, not Facebook in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large number of request, I would recommend that you read that page from the documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

It presents all the existing possibilities to issue requests in batch.

Best,